# How to disassemble .mbn files?

Tags: ida, disassembly

I can't disassemble .mbn files using ida pro 7+ if I use some scripts from GitHub than I can't disassemble any function, any help ?
I want to reverse qcom bootloader

Comment: You're referring to the Sony Ericsson phone firmware? Can you provide some additional detail on where the files came from and what scripts you are trying to use?

Comment: Nope, all qcom bootloader is same. [mbn files](https://osdn.net/projects/xiaomifirmwareupdater/storage/Stable/V10/sagit/fw_sagit_miui_MI6Global_V10.0.1.0.OCAMIFH_1f4296c44e_8.0.zip) and [script](https://github.com/Surge1223/ida-mbn-sbl-loader)